# PySpark 3.3.2: How to properly link OpenBLAS to speed up ML training?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark 3.3.2 for Machine Learning and I keep encountering the following warnings:

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

Due to these warnings, I believe my ML training is slow. I have already installed **libopenblas-dev (version 0.3.20+ds-1)** on my **Ubuntu**, but the warnings persist.

The official documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-linalg-guide.html) doesn't provide clear instructions on how to properly set up nativeLib/nativeLibPath. I have tried to configure it without any success.

Here's a code snippet to reproduce the issue, taken from the Spark documentation:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PySpark OpenBLAS Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/home/user/miniconda3/envs/egs_concur/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for logistic regression
print("Coefficients: " + str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(lrModel.intercept))

# We can also use the multinomial family for binary classification
mlr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8, family="multinomial")

# Fit the model
mlrModel = mlr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercepts for logistic regression with multinomial family
print("Multinomial coefficients: " + str(mlrModel.coefficientMatrix))
print("Multinomial intercepts: " + str(mlrModel.interceptVector))
```

How can I properly link OpenBLAS with PySpark to speed up my ML training and get rid of these warnings? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing open blas lib using conda,

as in
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openblas
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libopenblas
:
in your conda env run `conda install -c conda-forge openblas` `conda install -c conda-forge libopenblas`

Comment: I test this also, the result is the same:



```23/03/17 10:20:20 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
23/03/17 10:20:20 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS```


There should be some Spark settings pointing to this libs.